# I have tableA with column IMAGE_PATH ,I need subsisting from string

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

> IMAGE_PATH(Its column name)

```
   sph/images///////30_Fairhall_Court.jpeg
   sph/images///8_Furnival_Court.jpeg 
   sph/images/9_Pennethorne_House.jpeg
   rbkc/images/TAVISTOCK_CRESCENT.jpeg
   haringey///images/399932thumb.jpg
   urbanchoice/images//18190862.jpg
   westminster/images//7_Glarus_Court.jpeg
```

> I want to fetch substring from IMAGE_PATH Column as

```
30_Fairhall_Court
8_Furnival_Court
9_Pennethorne_House
TAVISTOCK_CRESCENT
399932thumb
18190862
7_Glarus_Court
```

> Means i need sub string between after last '/' and before '.' 
>   Please provide me solution how would be it fix

Comment: a `single slash` or `double` or `tripple` your data have three of them

Comment: it may be many times but i need result between   last occurrence of '/' and  before dot(.).

Comment: @Ameya Deshpande :-its give invalid LEFT identifier.

Comment: yes that was specific to `sqlserver` I didnt recognise your `oracle`

Comment: `regexp_substr('/sfs/sfsf/file_name.jpeg', '/([^./]+)[.](jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|gif)$', 1,1,NULL,1)`

Answer (score 4):

try this simple way (use `SUBSTR` with `INSTR`):

```
SELECT SUBSTR( image_path, INSTR(image_path, '/', -1)+1) "Image name"
FROM IMAGES;
```

**EDIT:** if you don't want to get `extension`s of files with `.` use:

```
SELECT SUBSTR( image_path, INSTR(image_path, '/', -1)+1,
               (INSTR(image_path, '.', -1))-INSTR(image_path, '/', -1)-1) "Image name"
FROM IMAGES;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
30_Fairhall_Court
8_Furnival_Court
9_Pennethorne_House
TAVISTOCK_CRESCENT
399932thumb
18190862
7_Glarus_Court
```

Answer (score 2):

You might try something like the following:

```
WITH d1 AS (
    SELECT 'sph/images///////30_Fairhall_Court.jpeg' AS image_path FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 'sph/images///8_Furnival_Court.jpeg' AS image_path FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 'sph/images/9_Pennethorne_House.jpeg' AS image_path FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 'rbkc/images/TAVISTOCK_CRESCENT.jpeg' AS image_path FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 'haringey///images/399932thumb.jpg' AS image_path FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 'urbanchoice/images//18190862.jpg' AS image_path FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 'westminster/images//7_Glarus_Court.jpeg' AS image_path FROM dual
)
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM REGEXP_SUBSTR(image_path, '[^/]+\.'))
  FROM d1;
```

The above does assume there are no `.` characters before the final `/`. A better solution might be:

```
WITH d1 AS (
    SELECT 'sph/images///////30_Fairhall_Court.jpeg' AS image_path FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 'sph/images///8_Furnival_Court.jpeg' AS image_path FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 'sph/images/9_Pennethorne_House.jpeg' AS image_path FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 'rbkc/images/TAVISTOCK_CRESCENT.jpeg' AS image_path FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 'haringey///images/399932thumb.jpg' AS image_path FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 'urbanchoice/images//18190862.jpg' AS image_path FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 'westminster/images//7_Glarus_Court.jpeg' AS image_path FROM dual
)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(image_path, '[^.]+', INSTR(image_path, '/', -1) + 1) 
  FROM d1;
```

That is, find all non-`.` (note that escaping the `.` isn't necessary inside the character class) characters after the final `/`.

Output:

```
30_Fairhall_Court
8_Furnival_Court
9_Pennethorne_House
TAVISTOCK_CRESCENT
399932thumb
18190862
7_Glarus_Court
```